# Where is the request argument coming from in pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a question with the request argument [in the following code](https://github.com/GokuMohandas/Made-With-ML/blob/540754392af9f49e637b491009586a61c54e2268/tests/model/conftest.py#L12):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def run_id(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--run-id")
```

In that line of code, where are we getting the `request` argument from? I searched the repo and `request` isn't defined as a fixture.

Comment: Try google "pytest scope"

Comment: Thanks. The poster of the answer just edited his answer.You can see that in the comment they posted to my question. More importantly the "request" argument in the second case, I am not sure where that comes from

Comment: It's a special fixture provided by pytest itself: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#std-fixture-request

Comment: @GinoMempin Thank you. I understood, why the request.config is used to access the options passed to command line

Answer (score 1):

The request fixture gets you access to a FixtureRequest instance. It is made available and injected manually by pytest for every test. It is used for accessing some pytest internals, in cases where you want to do something dynamic with pytest.

Its only mainstream use case (IMO) is being used in a fixture to provide access to the `request.param` attribute (for parametrized fixtures). In addition to it being a critical part of a lot of advanced / unusual pytest use cases.

Comment: For reference, link to the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#request